# Why is Lebesgue Measure called $\lambda$

Tags: reference-request, terminology

Why is the Lebesgue Measure is usually denoted by $\lambda$? Is it because Lebesgue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\lambda$ is the greek letter for $L$, which is the initial of Lebesgue.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I thought that al first, but I didn't find any source for that. I even thought that it would be from the word "long" (in French or English) because of the notion of lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$, so because of that i am asking (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: We used to use $\mathcal L$ for it... So maybe it's not universal?

Comment: @Shashi In my case $\mathcal{L}$ is for the Lebesgue measurable sets (sorry for my bad english)